# Exclude Select Click via Jquery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to trigger an action when I click anywhere on a tr with a class of parent. Excluding when I click on one of the dropdown boxes.

```
$('tr.parent')
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .click(function (e) {
        if($(e.target).not('select')){
            // do something
    }
```

Im trying the following but this is not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/0Lh5ozyb/60/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the issue for both Chrome and Firefox:

```
$('tr.parent')
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .click(function (e) {                   
        if ($(e.target).is('select') || $(e.target).is('option')) {
            //
        } else {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });

$('tr[class^=child-]').find('td > div, td').hide();
```

[JSFiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/malinkody/s981ve92/)

Edit: Simplified version if you don't need to do any action when the select is clicked.

```
$('tr.parent')
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .click(function (e) {               
        if (!($(e.target).is('select') || $(e.target).is('option'))) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        } 
    });

$('tr[class^=child-]').find('td > div, td').hide();
```

[JSFiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/malinkody/7pv8gbej/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$('tr.parent')
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .click(function (e) {
        if($(e.target).is("select"))
        {
          //... it was a select
        }
      else
       {
         //... it was not a select
       }
   }
```

Comment: A quick JSfiddle seems to show it as working, but I am curious. Do you know why `is` would work while `not` would not? Also, since we do not do anything for `select`, maybe you could adapt the test to be `$(e.target).is(':not(select)')` and drop the `else`, what do you think? (this should work too according to my JSFiddle)

Comment: @Chop Right :-) ......Also - both of results are TRUTHY values  - so even if you did : `$("body:input")` you will get `[]` which is an empty array but it IS TRUTHY so `if($("body:input"))` will still run as true

Comment: @felix001 Yes, it _does_ work. See a basic [JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lh5ozyb/66/).

Comment: Works in Chrome just not in FF (?)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `not` is a filter method. As such, it produces a jQuery object. When nothing matches it, it still returns an empty array, which is not a *falsy*. As a consequence, your test is always validated.

You can adapt your test using jQuery's test operator `is`, which checks whether your object matches a selector. Below is an optimization of [Royi Namir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30482014/1734119):

```
$('tr.parent')
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .click(function (e) {
        if($(e.target).is(":not(select)")) {
          //... it was not a select
        }
    });
```

Comment: @felix001 OK, this failed, but Royi Namir's solution works. Keep in mind you need to adapt the code you have in your handler: depending on the base selector and filters, `$(this)` is not the same. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lh5ozyb/66/).

Comment: @felix001 I was wrong, it does work. I was not testing the correct code. [New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lh5ozyb/67/).

Comment: Selecting enabled in the drop down causes it to go red (?)

Comment: @felix001 When I test, clicking on a line causes it to go red except when clicking the select.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/not/), You'd use `not` with them element descendants to attach that event!
Try this

```
 $('tr.parent *').not('select')
.css("cursor", "pointer")
.click(function (e) {
        // do something
   }
}
```

PS: this may attach the event more than once to an element contained in another descendant

Comment: I think this does not work because even if the event is not attached to the select, it is bound the cell (`<td/>`) the select is in. That is a shame as this would have been quite elegant (though attaching the handler to many more objects).